# Python: Given a Date and Weekday find the date of the next occurrence of a given weekday

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

This is a bit difficult to explain, so I apologize if this doesn't make much sense.

I have a program where I am doing some scheduling. One of the settings it has is to run a task weekly on certain days. For example, weekly on Monday, Wednesday and Friday.

Consider the example where the current task is scheduled for 1/2/2012, which is a Monday, I already have a bunch of code working to the point where I know the next task run should be on the wednesday following 1/2/2012. All I need to do is calculate the actual date of that Wednesday (1/4/2012).

I actually have the day of the week as the corresponding integer from date.weekday(), so in this case I have 2 which represents wednesday.

Whats the best way to handle something like this? I feel like there should be a fairly simple solution, but it isn't coming to mind. I was thinking of using a calendar object to search through to find the day of the week I want, but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) to add to a date. For example, using some date `d` as the scheduled date for a current task, and some day `next_day` (the next *day* you'd like to run the task).

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
...
n = (next_day - d.weekday()) % 7 # mod-7 ensures we don't go backward in time
next_run_date = d + timedelta(days=n)
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. It was off by several days when I ran my unit test with the change. I think what might throw things off is that in Python, Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6. I think Monday being 0 throws this off, but I am not sure.

Comment: I think you want `next_day - d.weekday()` instead.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRansom, I think you're right and I fixed my answer. @Jon, can you try it again? I don't think having Monday=0 should be a problem so long as `next_day` uses the same convention.

Comment: That does work now, thanks for the help. I was originally trying something very similar, but it just wasn't quite right. All of my unit tests are passing now.

Answer (score 14):

Use [dateutil.relativedelta](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-ba5ffd4df8111d1b83fc194b97ebecf837add454):

```
from dateutil import relativedelta
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
# datetime.date(2012, 1, 3)

today + relativedelta.relativedelta(weekday=2) # 2 is Wednesday
# datetime.date(2012, 1, 4)

today + relativedelta.relativedelta(weekday=6) # 6 is Sunday
# datetime.date(2012, 1, 8)

today + relativedelta.relativedelta(weekday=1) # 1 is Tuesday
# datetime.date(2012, 1, 3)
# returns today

today + relativedelta.relativedelta(weeks=1, weekday=1)
# datetime.date(2012, 1, 10)
# returns Tuesday at least one week ahead
```

Answer (score 0):

We know that:

- from **Monday** to **Wednesday** there is 2 days of difference.
- from **Wednesday** to **Friday** there is 2 days of difference.
- from **Friday** to **Monday** there is 3 days of difference.

So, this is as simple as adding the days of difference between scheduled tasks:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
first_scheduled_task = datetime(year=2012, month=1, day=2)
second_scheduled_task = first_scheduled_task + timedelta(2)
third_scheduled_task = second_scheduled_task + timedelta(2)
fourth_scheduled_task = third_scheduled_task + timedelta(3)
```

This would give us as result:

```
>>> first_scheduled_task
datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 2, 0, 0) # Monday 1/2/2012
>>> second_scheduled_task
datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 4, 0, 0) # Wednesday 1/4/2012
>>> third_scheduled_task
datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 6, 0, 0) # Friday 1/6/2012
>>> fourth_scheduled_task
datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 9, 0, 0) # Monday 1/9/2012
```

Comment: I should clarify I was using Monday and Wednesday as a generic example. The repeat could be any combination of days. For example, Monday, Thursday, Saturday. So this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) for working with scheduling and recurrences.